# Daylite CRM Equivalent on Windows 7

Tags: crm

Daylite seems to be the perfect solution for my needs, but I have a PC.  I can't run VMWare and don't want to use cloud based services and buying a Mac is not an option.

What is a good, local, CRM software for Windows?